# If N is a nilpotent subgroup of a group G and G' is a commutator of G then show that [N,G']=1

Tags: group-theory

I try this but unable to find a relation between nilpotent subgroup and commutator 
Sinc N is nilpotent so Ni is a subgroup of zi (G) then no idia how to proceed further

Comment: Jyrki lahtonen Thank you so much

Comment: Take $G=S_3$, $N=\{1,(12)\}$, your statement seems confusing to me. Perhaps, you may have to write "$N$ is *cyclic*.

Comment: N is just nilpotent sir

Comment: did you consider my example? $N$ is a cyclic group so nilpotent.

Comment: Yes i consider your example but my question is how we prove this ingenral

Comment: E.g G=Q8 is nilpotent and H is a subgroup of G such that |H|=4 then |G/H|=2 so [H,G']=1 how we prove this for a genral case